# Why does my if in a loop make a beep

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, pyautogui

I'm using [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to click on a button that periodically pops up on my GUI as shown in the script below. However when the button is not on the screen, the script makes two annoying beep sounds while going through the loop.

If I replace `pyautogui.locateOnScreen(...)` with `None`, which seems to be the return value if the image can't be located on the screen, the sound seems to disappear.

The script runs in a Jupyter Notebook (v4) using python 2.7 and I'm on Debian 8.1 with Gnome.

```
import pyautogui
import time

starttime = time.time()  

while time.time()-starttime<10:
    img_path_inactive = "/home/user/folder/inactive_target.png"
    img_path_active = "/home/user/folder/active_target.png"
    img_list = [img_path_inactive, img_path_active]
    get_target = map(pyautogui.locateOnScreen, img_list)  # <--- This line beeps! See edit 2

    if any(get_target):
        pyautogui.click(filter(None, get_target)[0][0], filter(None, get_target)[0][1])

    # The if check above was previously (hence the title):
    # if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(img_path_active) or pyautogui.locateOnScreen(img_path_inactive):
    #     click_target = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(img_path_active) or pyautogui.locateOnScreen(img_path_inactive)
    #     pyautogui.click(click_target[0], click_target[1])

    time.sleep(2)

print("Finished loop.")
```

**Edit**

I put the script in a .py file and ran it from the command line to check if it is a jupyter thing. It still beeped though.

Afterwards I ran `pyautogui.locateOnScreen` against three images, which caused predictably three beeps... So it definitely seems to be a pyautogui issue/'feature'...

**Edit 2**

`pyautogui.locateOnScreen` is imported from [here](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/blob/master/pyscreeze/__init__.py), see line 238. It actually does seem to raise an exception:

```
    except ImageNotFoundException:
        if time.time() - start > minSearchTime:
            raise
```

Comment: try adding a parenthesis to the whole `if` condition

Comment: @CrakC It still beeps twice... :( I changed it to `if (pyautogui.locateOnScreen(img_path_active) or pyautogui.locateOnScreen(img_path_inactive))`

Comment: @CrakC Those are not necessary in python.

Comment: Just to be proper: `if` is not a loop :)

Comment: @pandita Please elaborate more on what happens vs. what should be happening.

Comment: @Alex.S Who said it is? Edit: Oh, in the title. I didn't notice, thought you mean in the question.

Comment: @D.Everhard What happens is that the script triggers a system beep. What should happen is that the script doesn't trigger a system beep. The rest of it works.

Comment: @Alex.S Fixed the title :) ... :( not the problem though...

Comment: Do you get any exception when the beeps occur?

Comment: @SiHa No it completes without an exception

Comment: Have you tried clicking the button manually to see if the button itself causes the sound?

Comment: @D.Everhard The sound occurs when the button does not exists on the screen, not when it is clicked

Comment: Just as an aside - you're running `pyautogui.locateOnScreen` (a slow function call), potentially four times in each execution of your loop. You could speed things up considerably by refactoring your code.

Comment: Try printing the value of pyautogui.locateOnScreen(...) to see what it returns when it doesn't find the image. Since the sound didn't occur when you replaced it with None, maybe it returns something else.

Comment: @D.Everhard It may not matter but its not really about python, its about precedence and when it comes to precedence, its better to have parenthesis in order to produce code that runs the same everywhere. I hope you understand what I am trying to say here.

Comment: @SiHa, thanks for the heads up. I did this a bit already when running it from the terminal and will update it soon. Anyway, I found the source of `locateOnScreen` and it actually seems to raise an exception when an image is not found. I'm on Gnome. Do you know how I could configure it to raise the exception silently? Ideally for this script only?

Comment: @D.Everhard Printing `pyautogui.locateOnScreen(...)` returns `None` as mentioned...

Comment: Can you just catch it without handling it, to suppress the exception?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also on GNU/Linux and experiencing beeping when the pyautogui.locateOnScreen() function runs (whether or not it locates the image).

I found that scrot is the culprit. The solution:

1. $ sudo mv /usr/bin/scrot /usr/bin/scrot-noisy
2. Create /usr/bin/scrot with these contents:

#!/bin/bash

scrot-noisy --silent "$@"

3. $ sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/scrot

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a workaround to the beeping.

After going to the [source of the module](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/blob/master/pyscreeze/__init__.py) from which `pyautogui.locateOnScreen` is imported, I believe that the function raises a custom ImageNotFoundException somewhere down the track. I didn't fully debug it though.

Being on Gnome, all Exceptions are announced by an annoying beep.

The workaround that did it for me was to [turn off the system beep altogether](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-linux-disable-or-turn-off-beep-sound-for-terminal/).

I added the following line to `~/.xsession`:

```
xset b off
```

which killed the beep.